# Sonar 3.7 XML Profile XHTML Validation Failure

Tags: tomcat, proxy, jenkins, xhtml, sonarqube

I'm trying to add Sonar Web and XML quality profile analysis to my stable suite of Java profile analyses. Sonar XML quality profile analysis is unable to complete XHTML validation. I suspect the issue is the validation engine is unable to access the XML schema via the internet due to proxy issues.

Error:

```
[INFO] [11:48:07.587] Sensor XmlSourceImporter...
[INFO] [11:48:23.354] Sensor XmlSourceImporter done: 15767 ms
[INFO] [11:48:23.354] Sensor XmlSensor...
[INFO] [11:48:23.557] Validate Exit.xhtml with schema xhtml1-transitional
[ERROR] [11:48:44.542] Could not analyze the file D:\Jenkins_home\.jenkins\jobs\...\Exit.xhtml
org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.sonar.plugins.xml.checks.XmlSchemaCheck.validate(XmlSchemaCheck.java:248) ~[na:na]
    at org.sonar.plugins.xml.checks.XmlSchemaCheck.validate(XmlSchemaCheck.java:227) ~[na:na]
    at org.sonar.plugins.xml.checks.XmlSchemaCheck.validate(XmlSchemaCheck.java:259) ~[na:na]
    at org.sonar.plugins.xml.XmlSensor.analyse(XmlSensor.java:69) ~[na:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:72) [sonar-batch-3.7.1.jar:na]
```

Configuration:

- Tomcat 7.0.11 with Jenkins 1.509.3 and Sonar 3.7.1 installed into Tomcat on Windows Server 2003.
- Plugin versions: Sonar XML version 1.0, Jenkins Sonar version 2.1, Jenkins Subversion 1.50.
- Jenkins Maven 2.2.1 jobs triggering Sonar analysis.
- All web access secured with proxy server (corporate configuration).
- Sonar configured with proxy server properties in conf/sonar.properties (proof: able to access Sonar Update Centre - if Tomcat proxy switches configured to allow proxy access per below).
- Tomcat Java process configured with empty -Dhttp.proxyHost and -Dhttp.proxyPort switches to suppress proxy settings being passed from Windows. This was needed so proxy information wasn't passed to Jenkins (Jenkins Subversion access fails if proxy switches are passed from Tomcat).

I think I'm in a catch 22 where I need Tomcat to suppress proxy settings so Jenkins Subversion access works, but need Tomcat proxy settings for Sonar XML analysis to work. Maybe I need to drop Tomcat in favour of stand-alone installations of Jenkins and Sonar?

Am I correct in my proxy setting analysis and/or is there another Sonar configuration I can attempt to get XHTML validation to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by configuring the Maven installation used by Jenkins to use a proxy to connect to the network. Reference: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html. Within the Maven proxy configuration, I added the intranet URI (`*.<corporate-domain-root>.*`) within `<nonProxyHosts>`.

The Sonar proxy server properties in *conf/sonar.properties* are not required.

So now, Jenkins and Sonar are initiated via Tomcat without proxy settings (ie empty `-Dhttp.proxyHost` and `-Dhttp.proxyPort` switches). When the Jenkins job triggers the Sonar analysis via Maven, Maven is able to call out to the internet via the proxy configuration when doing the XML schema validation check.